# Can't Find Garamond Font

Tags: fonts, texlive, linux

I'm using TeX Live right now on ArchLinux with VS Code and [James Yu's LaTeX Workshop](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=James-Yu.latex-workshop) or `pdflatex`. Here is my `latex-v`:

```
pdfTeX 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.25 (TeX Live 2023/Arch Linux)
kpathsea version 6.3.5
Copyright 2023 Han The Thanh (pdfTeX) et al.
There is NO warranty.  Redistribution of this software is
covered by the terms of both the pdfTeX copyright and
the Lesser GNU General Public License.
For more information about these matters, see the file
named COPYING and the pdfTeX source.
Primary author of pdfTeX: Han The Thanh (pdfTeX) et al.
Compiled with libpng 1.6.39; using libpng 1.6.39
Compiled with zlib 1.2.13; using zlib 1.2.13
Compiled with xpdf version 4.04
```

I've tried many ways of using Garamond (e.g. `\usepackage{ebgaramond}`), which is supposedly packed in TeX Live as far as I know.

When I run it on VS Code, I get:

```
File `ebgaramond.sty' not found.
```

What am I missing? Do I need to install extra stuff? (I've installed TeX Live through AUR's [`texlive-full`](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/texlive-full))

Answer (score 1):

Can you switch to the `lualatex` compiler, and use the `fontspec` package for loading fonts? With `fontspec` you can load fonts directly by font name, even if it is a system (rather than TeX) font.

When you write `\usepackage` or `\RequestPackage` TeX looks for a `*.sty` file. Even if you are looking for fonts, it will look for `FontName.sty` rather than `FontName.otf` or other font type.

Some font packages require their own `*.sty` file, which contains information about math substitutions and other stuff. Some font packages may provide a dummy `*.sty` file, just in case TeX looks for it.

Try this, compiled with `lualatex` not `pdflatex` (and be sure that everything is utf-8 encoded):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{EB Garamond} % Assumes that you have the fonts already.
\begin{document}
Hello, World!
\end{document}
```

Comment: Didn't work with either `lualatex` or `xelatex`. They don't have the font either apparently. How do I install the font package?

Comment: Certainly font EB Garamond works. Package `ebgaramond` should install. Do not confuse witholder fonts named only GARAMOND.

Comment: My `lualatex` is pointing to `LuaHBTeX`, and I get `! LaTeX Error: File \`EBGaramond.sty' not found.`

Comment: @PhilippeFanaro Sorry, I cannot help. Works for me, and does not look for the `*sty` file. But then, I do not write math expressions, so maybe that is the issue.